# Data from django model form not being saved to database

Tags: django, django-forms

I created a model form with a few fields and would like to save the data when a user enters values into the template and clicks submit.
However when I click 'submit' the values are not cleared from the form, and the data is not getting saved into the sqlite3 database which I checked using `select * from notes_note;`

I am not getting any error, it simply isn't saving that data.

**Models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class Note(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING,)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    createTime = models.DateTimeField()

from django.forms import ModelForm

class NoteForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        #fields = '__all__'
        #fields = ['title', 'text', 'createTime']
        exclude = ['owner']
```

**Template**

```
<a href="/notes/logout/">Log Out</a>
<h2>Dashboard {{ user }}</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form_name="noteForm" action="/notes/dashboard/" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <input type= "submit" value="New Note"/>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url="/notes/index/")
def dashboard(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # d dict is a copy of our request.Post because it's immutable and we need to add owner
        d = request.POST.copy()
        d.update({'owner': request.user.id})
        form = NoteForm(d)
        if not form.is_valid():
            template = loader.get_template('dashboard.html')
            context = {
                'form': form,
            }
            return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request=request))
        # save the note to the database
        # if the form is valid
        note = form.save()
        note.owner = request.user
        note.save()
        return redirect("dashboard")
    else:
        print("this prints out")
        template = loader.get_template('dashboard.html')
        context = {
            'form': NoteForm(),
        }
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request=request))
```

I checked using a print statement in my dashboard function in views.py to see what is being processed, and it is hitting the else portion.

Comment: `<form_name` typo?

Comment: Yup! that seems to have been the issue, thanks a lot!